# In aarch64 two stage page table translation, how will the exception level change?

Tags: paging, arm64, cpu-registers, armv8, page-fault

In two stage page table translation process, I think stage-1 is in el1 and the guestOS is responsible for translating by TTBR0_EL1. As for stage-2 translation, I think the hypervisor in EL2 is responsible for this. In stage-2 translation, VTTBR_EL2 is used. After stage-1 translation, how does the exception level change so that the system can access register in EL2？Could someone describe the detail of two stage translation, including related registers, assembly instruction and how the exception level changes.

Comment: It is unlikely that it as you stated.  The higher priveledge could be responsible for the first stage.  It would be worthwhile to point to some reference information and show more research.

Comment: The actual translation is done by the hardware; the OS and hypervisor are only responsible for setting up the tables.  Translation (both levels) happens on every memory access and doesn't in itself involve an exception level change.  The `_ELx` registers still control the operation of the system at all lower exception levels; it's just that you have to be at ELx in order to read or write the register from software (i.e. `mrs/msr` instructions).

Comment: Translation process, no matter how many stages involved, not changing `ELx` where memory access instruction is executed in normal case. Exception generated by MMU if translation fails. What happens next depends on configuration and EL which generated failed memory access. All details in 'ARMv8 Technical Reference Manual'